# Read all files of a specified type from classloader

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, maven-3

I have a number of JSON files that I have created using the ObjectMapper class.  I have another module which I want to have these files placed in src/main/resources.  I want to map these back to Java objects for use in my spring web service.

I don't believe that I can do anything in my context.xml to deal with these. If I can can somebody please explain.

I was hoping that I could get a list of all the files easily, then iterate the list to deserialize.  However I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to get at the root folder of the class path.  This must be possible but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: [What have you tried that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Spring's [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:*.json");
```

Comment: Great! Spring has a ton of cool utilities. Could you do me a favor accept the answer, please?